# Dilute DNA plasmids with distilled water

Tags: dna, plasmids

I just extracted the DNA plasmid from *E.Coli* and dilute them in EB buffer. However, I've just figured out that the next step, which is electroporation, required that the DNA plasmid be diluted in Distilled H<sub>2</sub>O. Can anybody help me to know how to transfer the DNA plasmid from EB buffer to Distilled H<sub>2</sub>O?
To be clear, the EB buffer I used is from Qiagen. It contains 10mM Tris-Cl, pH 8.5.
https://www.qiagen.com/sg/resources/faq?id=d8ef773f-6a37-4993-908b-8bbc7bc5c8d6&lang=en

Comment: EB buffer is just Tris isn't it? I don't think that would interfere with electroporation. If you must change, you could precipitate or dialyse.

Comment: Please define EB buffer. In general avoid lab slang. I have edited your question to do so regarding distilled water, but I have no idea what EB buffer is and if it is not defined will vote to close your question as unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Buffer EB is simply 10mM Tris buffer, ph 8.5. I think you are worried about the ions present in your electroporation. There are two things to consider:

1. What is the concentration of your DNA and how much do you need for the electroporation?
2. In which final volume is the electroporation taking place?

In my experience, usually you add a very small amount of DNA (a few microliters) to 100, 250 or 400µl (depending on the cuvettes used) final volume. Here a tiny amount of Tris does not interfere or cause a short circuit.